# how to force variable declaration in javascript or how to check it?

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration

Though you can use a variable without declaring it in javascript, the misuse of variable will cause hard-to-solve errors. For example, the following code will cause endless loop.

```
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    document.write(fiveTimes(i));
  }
  ...

  function fiveTimes(x){
    i=5;
    return (i*x);
  }
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to force every variable in the javascript to be declared before use. Or anybody knows how to check for variable declaration-before-using in tons of javascript files and blocks in a huge web server.

Comment: You're looking for JSHint.

Comment: Technically the code i=5 is a valid declaration of a javascript variable. It's just declared onto the global scope instead of the local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable ["Strict Mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) and you can pass your code through [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) (Or [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/) if you have sensitive feelings :))These steps will go a long way toward making your code execute predictably.

Comment: jsLint isn't worth it, use jsHint instead. Life is short.

Comment: I'm more of a massocist. I like jsLint. I prefer my linters to make fun of me :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Let me guess, because of `for (var i = 0` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, Ian.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Well, the whole "all variables should be declared at the beginning of the scope" is broken by using `for (var i = 0` (which many people use that convention) and jsLint stops checking the file when it finds this specific occurrence. And there's no way of turning that on or off in the options. At least I thought that was a problem. And I know people don't like it

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Otherwise, what's your reason for being against jsLint? Honestly just wondering

Comment: Oh. Yeah, but that's just one of the things--jsLint is just too strict overall, I feel. I don't like Crockford much, either. I mean, he's dead on with a lot of stuff, but his opinion of himself and his coding practices just rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Haha that's funny you say that about Crockford...for some reason, I completely agree. And about jsLint - for some reason, I like the over-strictness, so that's why I stick with it. I'm sure I'd be happier if I used jsHint...

Comment: I read Crockfords's take on hoisting verses code cleanliness and I think it's compelling. If JavaScript were block scoped then this might now be a a big deal but it's function scoped so you have to treat it differently. I haven't been persuaded to switch to jsHint yet. I think if you are going to hold your code to a standard then it should be as high a standard as possible. Plus the issues that are considered dogmatic seem reasonable to me.

Comment: I think a lot of people feel that way. :P Plus, you can configure jsHint a lot more than jsLint--you can even get them to behave the same way if you want, but it's easy to change anything you find annoying, unlike with Lint.

Comment: @user2279231: To ease your googling, it's `strict mode` not `restrict mode`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville That's true. And maybe I'm just too lazy to look into that now :) We already have it automatically scanning our code when we build, and it works. Maybe when I have time, I'll look into changing that :) It's probably not that hard anyways

Comment: Another fun tool, that may do more than needed here, is Google's Closure Compiler - https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/ . I have yet to look into it or use it :)

Comment: That's a really neat tool, Ian, I'll have to check it out.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Yeah, the tools that are out there never cease to amaze me. I'm sure I could benefit from plenty of them, I just never take the time to learn/use them. The Closure Compiler does a lot more than just be a linter

Answer (score 1):

The main architecture behind JavaScript doesn't allow you to achieve this without parsing the code with another compiler ( jsHint, etc ... ). What will happen there is that the library will double check your code for some dangerous ( unwanted ) results. If you are good enough and know what you are doing, you can avoid using those and just be careful of what you are doing.

Also, there are a lot of languages that compile to JS ( CoffeeScript, etc. ) that has automatic variable declaration for every function and more stuff you might be interested in.

This solution has to tell you that JavaScript isn't supposed to do that internally and there is no forced use of 'strict' mode at least at this time.